# Определить сумму элементов, расположенных между минимальным и максимальным. Нужно сделать через указатели

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели

Попытался написать код но что-то не вышло. 
Макс  и минимальный элементы были найдены ранее осталось только найти сумму элементов между минимальным и максимальным элементом массива.

```
p = A;
int Sum = 0, Smin=0, Smax=0;
do {
    p = A;
    Sum += *p;
    if ((*p) > 0 && (!(*min) || (*p) < (*min)) || (*p) < 0 && (!(*min) || (*p) < (*min))) {     
        Smin = Sum;
    }

    if ((*p) > 0 && (!(*max) || (*p) > (*max))) {       
        Smax = Sum;
    }
} while (p==A);

if (Smax >= Smin) {
    Sum = Smin - Smax;
}
else {
    Sum = Smin - Smax;
}

cout << Sum << endl;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int min_max_sum(int * a, int N)
{
    int * min = a, * max = a;
    for(int * p = a; p < a + N; ++p)
    {
        if (*min > *p) min = p;
        else if (*max < *p) max = p;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    if (min > max)
    {
        int * tmp = min;
        min = max;
        max = tmp;
    }
    for(int *p = min+1; p < max; ++p) sum += *p;

    return sum;
}
```

Comment: если  *min > *p, может лучше обойти проверку *max < *p  ?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Можно даже еще интереснее - читать сразу два значения, сравнивать между собой, потом меньшее - с min, большее - с max; итого - 1.5 сравнений на элемент :)